# How to access ItemsControl's ItemsSource element from the ItemsControl's Item's code behind?

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, code-behind

In my main view I have an ItemsControl which is bound to a collection of objects:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Concepts}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ActivationLevelTemplate}"
              />
```

Where the ActivationLevelTemplate is just another view:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ActivationLevelTemplate">
    <view:ConceptActivationView Height="50"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

In this view there is a text block, bound to a property of an object from the collection mentioned above. The property is displayed correctly, and now I need to access other properties of the same object from the view's code behind. It seems trivial but I could not get it working.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           />
<d3:Plotter2D Name="Plotter"/>
```

---

The best thing I came across was `ItemContainerGenerator` but it does not seem to be what is needed.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the code behind?

Comment: I need to get some graph data from the object to plot some lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is important is the context in which you try to access that object. If you for example deal with an event inside the DataTemplate you can easily get the object from the DataContext of the sender (has to be a FrameworkElement), e.g. if i were to handle a button click:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var employee = (Employee)button.DataContext;
    //...
}
```

In fact if your whole view is inside the DataTemplate you can get the object directly from the View's DataContext as well.

Comment: Oh, DataContext as Employee! That was so simple! Thank you so much! It works now.

Comment: Glad that helped :) (You can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark outline on the left of the answer)

Comment: how to access the sibling buttons, for example, I need to clear the previous button style when I click current one?

Comment: @Batur: You should link them either in your data or in the XAML using bindings/references beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to iterate through the items in the ItemsControl and get all the properties you need. Give the ItemsControl a name so you can address it in the code behind:

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl" ... />
```

Then in code behind

```
foreach (YourItem item in itemsControl.Items)
{
    // your logic...
}
```

If you need a specific item you could try CurrentItem or GetItemAt() instead

```
itemsControl.Items.CurrentItem
// or
itemsControl.Items.GetItemAt()
```